# Page links are not working after moving domain

Tags: pagination

Recently, I have moved a domain for my wordpres. But facing some strange problems:

[0] OS - CentOS

[1] All the pages/notices/media are not showing on admin; though they are all in database.

[2] The pages I found are under posts but I can't preview them.

[3] If I do link any page with menu, the page links do not work.

May be I am missing some configuration. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from Codex:

> When your domain name or URLs change there are additional concerns.
>   The files and database can be moved, however references to the old
>   domain name or location will remain in the database, and that can
>   cause issues with links or theme display.
>
> If you do a search and replace on your entire database to change the
>   URLs, you can cause issues with data serialization, due to the fact
>   that some themes and widgets store values with the length of your URL
>   marked. When this changes, things break. To avoid that serialization
>   issue, you have four options:
>
> - Use the Velvet Blues Update URLs plugin if you can access your WP
>     Admin Dashboard.
> - Use the Better Search Replace plugin if you can access your WP Admin Dashboard.
> - Use WP-CLI's search-replace if your hosting provider (or you) have installed WP-CLI.
> - Use the [Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to safely change all instances
>     on your old domain or path to your new one. (** only use this option
>     if you are comfortable with database administration ** )

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to go to your Permalinks in the Settings, and HIT Save/Update.

Sometimes this will do a hard refresh on them and update them in your database to the new URL's or IP address reflected.

Otherwise, check your database and see if the URL's that are  in your tables are matching your current URL's and also make sure they URL's are not hard-coded in your page templates or code anywhere.

A URL would also help us out too. ;) I can help personally too my email is mikeisrain@gmail.com if you want to share more info. Then we can circle back here and post a proper/correct solution.

Comment: Hello Michael:

Thank you for your response. The site is on a private VPN yet.
And I have requested you to add me in skype so that we can discuss deepening down the problem. Please check your mail

Comment: It won’t be enough. There can be images or links in posts or widgets and they are stored text, so updating permalinks won’t change such links.